# FileNotFoundException: /acct/uid_99315/pid_1778/cgroup.procs while accessing native lib in Xiaomi MIUI GLobal 10.1

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, xiaomi, miui

currently i'm handling Android application that built using Cordova. My application was running well while accessing Android native lib. Until one day i upgraded my device testing Xiaomi MIUI Version into the latest one, MIUI Global 10.1 i got error bellow :

```
2019-02-21 14:59:11.662 1456-2915/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /acct/uid_99319/pid_7472/cgroup.procs (No such file or directory)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.miui.server.PerfShielderService.setForkedProcessGroup(PerfShielderService.java:217)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService.setForkedProcessGroup(ExtraActivityManagerService.java:1267)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerServiceInjector.setForkedProcessGroup(ActivityManagerServiceInjector.java:1017)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.applyOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22819)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:23441)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1438)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1007)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7463)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:7530)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:292)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3023)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.678 1456-2915/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:704)
2019-02-21 14:59:11.679 1456-2915/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2019-02-21 14:59:11.679 1456-2915/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 320
2019-02-21 14:59:11.679 1456-2915/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
```

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: still not get the solution. did you ?